# Beginner C++ avoiding repetitive if/else if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, repeat

I am working on a seating chart program. The purpose of the program is to display a seating chart with seat prices and allow users to select either a specific seat or a seat based off price. I've pretty much got it working properly with a few exceptions.

I posted on here with a question regarding one of those exceptions but was quickly informed that first I needed to address the issue of the repetitive code for each price. I need to figure out a single chunk of code that will implement this for every price range. I've looked it over but not quite sure where to start. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 9;
const int COLUMNS = 10;



int main()
{
    bool isDone = false;

    string rowNumber[] =
    {
        "Row 1:  ",
        "Row 2:  ",
        "Row 3:  ",
        "Row 4:  ",
        "Row 5:  ",
        "Row 6:  ",
        "Row 7:  ",
        "Row 8:  ",
        "Row 9:  ",
    };

    int seatingChart[ROWS][COLUMNS] =
    {
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
        {20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20},
        {20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 30, 20},
        {30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30},

    };


    // Prints array to the screen
    cout << "\t      Please choose a seat or a price: \n\n" << endl;
    cout << "        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10" << endl;
    cout << "        --------------------------------------" << endl;

    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        cout << rowNumber[row];

        for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
        {
            cout << seatingChart[row][column] << "  ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    // Main Program Loop
    do
    {
    char input;

    cout << "Press (S) to select a specific seat\n";
    cout << "Press (P) to select a seat based on price\n";
    cout << "Press (Q) to quit\n\n";
    cout << "Your selection: ";
    cin >> input;

    // Select a specific seat by it's coordinates
    if (input == 's' || input == 'S')
    {
        int xCoord;
        int yCoord;

        cout << "\nPlease input the row number: ";
        cin >> yCoord;

        int seatRow = yCoord - 1;

        cout << "Please input the seat number: ";
        cin >> xCoord;

        int seatNumber = xCoord - 1;

            if (seatingChart[seatRow][seatNumber] == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nI'm sorry that seat has been sold. Please select a different seat." << endl;
            }else
            {
                cout << "\nThe seat you selected is $" << seatingChart[seatRow][seatNumber] << endl;

                seatingChart[seatRow][seatNumber] = 0;
            }


    // Select a seat based off of price
    }else if (input == 'p' || input == 'P')
    {
        int seatPrice;
        cout << "Please enter a seat price: $";
        cin >> seatPrice;

        // $10 seats
        if (seatPrice == 10)
        {
            bool found = false;

            while (found == false)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
                    {
                        if (seatingChart[row][column] == 10 && !found)
                        {
                            found = true;

                            seatingChart[row][column] = 0;

                            cout << "\n" << endl;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // $20 seats
        else if (seatPrice == 20)
        {
            bool found = false;

            while (found == false)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
                    {
                        if (seatingChart[row][column] == 20 && !found)
                        {
                            found = true;

                            seatingChart[row][column] = 0;

                            cout << "\n" << endl;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        // $30 seats
        else if (seatPrice == 30)
        {
            bool found = false;

            while (found == false)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
                    {
                        if (seatingChart[row][column] == 30 && !found)
                        {
                            found = true;

                            seatingChart[row][column] = 0;

                            cout << "\n" << endl;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        // $40 seats
        else if (seatPrice == 40)
        {
            bool found = false;

            while (found == false)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
                    {
                        if (seatingChart[row][column] == 40 && !found)
                        {
                            found = true;

                            seatingChart[row][column] = 0;

                            cout << "\n" << endl;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        // $50 seats
        else if (seatPrice == 50)
        {
            bool found = false;

            while (found == false)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
                    {
                        if (seatingChart[row][column] == 50 && !found)
                        {
                            found = true;

                            seatingChart[row][column] = 0;

                            cout << "\n" << endl;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }else // Input validation
        {
            cin.fail();
            cout << "\nSorry, there are no seats available for that price" << endl;
        }

    }else if (input == 'q' || input == 'Q')
    {
        isDone = true;
    }else
    {
        cin.fail();
        cout << "\nInvalid selection" << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    }while (isDone == false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you know all about the `||` operator. Can you think of a way to have a single `if()` statement to check that the entered price is one of the several acceptable prices, and, if so, execute the rest of the logic, referring to the variable that specified the price? Just one `if()` statement that checks if the price is 10, ***or*** 20, ***or*** 30, and so on...

Comment: You may want to give `switch` sentence or table driven a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know everything you need.

To check if the seat price is valid, use `||`:

```
if (seatPrice == 10 || seatPrice == 20 || seatPrice == 30)
{
    find a seat
}
else
{
    tell user that price is invalid
}
```

and to check if the seat price is equal to the price the user entered, use `seatingChart[row][column] == seatPrice` (instead of a fixed number 10, 20, 30, 40 or 50).

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately I was able to figure this out on my own once I went back and gave it some thought